# How to assign entity to another entity in a form using ThymeLeaf?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

I am working on MVC Java project and am using Spring Boot with ThymeLeaf. The issue I have is, that when creating a Task, I want to select and save a User, that will be assign to the task. I managed to do the selection correctly, but am unable to save the selected user. It always saves without the User assigned.

Here is my Task entity class:

```
@Entity
public class Task extends BaseEntity {

    private String name;

    private String description;

    private Date dateOfCreation;

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date dueDate;

    @ManyToOne
    private User assignee;

    public Task() {
        this.dateOfCreation = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
    }
}
```

My User entity is as follows:

```
@Entity
public class User extends BaseEntity {

    private String username;

    private String password;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "assignee")
    private List<Task> assignedTasks;
}
```

Where BaseEntity contains

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;

@Version
private Integer version;
```

My controller function, that is responsible for my taskform.html is:

```
@RequestMapping("/new")
public String newTask(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("task", new Task());
    model.addAttribute("users", userService.getAllUsers());
    return "task/taskform";
}
```

And my taskform.html looks like this:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" th:object="${task}" th:action="@{/task}" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}"/>
    <input type="hidden" th:field="*{version}"/>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{name}"/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Description:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{description}"/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Description:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="date" th:value="*{dueDate}" th:field="*{dueDate}" id="dueDate" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Select user:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <select class="form-control">
                <option th:field="*{assignee}" th:each="assignee : ${users}" th:value="${assignee}" th:text="${assignee.username}">
                </option>
            </select>
         </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </div>
```

I am trying to pass the object from users list as the value, but it does not work Any idea, how to do it?

Showing the users works as expected:

[Working frontend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xr1kL.png)

Null is being assigned to assignee column, where the user should be assigned.

[Null in H2 Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41zG8.png)

**EDIT**

Here is my POST method from Task Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveOrUpdate(Task task){
    taskService.persistTask(task);
    return "redirect:/task/list";
}
```

Comment: how does your post method looks like?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I updated the question with the appropriate POST method.

Comment: If you set a breakpoint in the saveOrUpdate method do is the user assigned?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli, the user is not assigned. Assignee is null.